Error in uploading document from React to SharePoint with Graph API
I am uploading a file from React to SharePoint with Graph API and MSAL Library for authorization.
I have received the authorized graphClient and also accessToken (bearer token). Now, When I try to upload file to sharepoint, I get following error:

400 Bad Request. Error uploading file Error: Resource not found for
the segment 'getByPath'.
at _GraphErrorHandler.constructErrorFromResponse (@microsoft_microsoft-graph-client.js?v=41398962:2606:20)
at _GraphErrorHandler. (@microsoft_microsoft-graph-client.js?v=41398962:2631:37)
at Generator.next ()
at @microsoft_microsoft-graph-client.js?v=41398962:30:67
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (@microsoft_microsoft-graph-client.js?v=41398962:12:10)
at _GraphErrorHandler.getError (@microsoft_microsoft-graph-client.js?v=41398962:2628:12)
at GraphRequest. (@microsoft_microsoft-graph-client.js?v=41398962:2894:48)
at Generator.throw ()
at rejected (@microsoft_microsoft-graph-client.js?v=41398962:22:32)

I have implementation following logic to to upload file: (siteId, driveId and other parametrs are correct).
When I use the same url to get list of files in Sharepoint drive from Graph Explorer then it works properly, but gives error in React
try {
        const fileName = file.name;
        const fileToUpload = file

        const response = await client
                 .api(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/drives/${driveId}:/${activityNumber}/${fileName}:/content`)
         .put(fileToUpload);
  
        console.log("File uploaded successfully!");
        console.log(response)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading file", error);


You are calling sites/{site_id}/lists endpoint, but you using driveId instead of listId. It's weird.
